# Adding properties to the form in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Am adding properties to the active form but it isn't working

Am using a wbranca's dynamic form that needs to pass a form id in the begin form and also in the same form there is a file uploader that requires'options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'

```
I have tried 
 <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'dynamic-form']
,['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>
the form cant upload
```

When I interchange the two like below the form id is not rendered so the dynamic forms can't work

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'],
,(['id' => 'dynamic-form']]); ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code ;

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'],,(['id' => 'dynamic-form']]); ?>
```

- You have not open bracket `'('` after ActiveForm::begin.
- 2 Comma used between `form-data'],,(['id'`
- Unnecessary used `'()'` in 'id' part. And, didn't closed properly.

Use this. It will work

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'],'id' => 'dynamic-form']); ?>
```